# Prove that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x^{2}y}{x^{4}-2x^{2}y + 5y^{2}}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Wolframalpha says that

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3x^{2}y}{x^{4}-2x^{2}y + 5y^{2}}$$

does not exist.

But I can not find a way to prove it, using $\gamma1(t) = (0,t)$, $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$ and $\gamma(t) = (t,t)$ gives me zero.

Can anyone please, help me?

Comment: hint: try a curve other than a straight line

Comment: try (x,y)=(t,t^2), it should converge to non zero limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curves $\gamma_{1}(t) = (t,t^{2})$ and $\gamma_{2}(t) = (t,-t^{2})$. If the limit existed, the limit of the composition should be the same, but this is not the case. Indeed, on one hand, the limit along $\gamma_{1}$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{3t^{4}}{t^{4} - 2t^{4} + 5t^{4}} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the limit along $\gamma_{2}$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-3t^{4}}{t^{4} + 2t^{4} + 5t^{4}} = -\frac{3}{8}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: What does $\gamma$ represent?

Comment: @FouadSaffar Each $\gamma_{k}$ is a vector-valued function with real domain. Precisely speaking, $\gamma_{1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is given by $\gamma_{1}(t) = (t,t^{2})$ whereas $\gamma_{2}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is given by $\gamma_{1}(t) = (t,-t^{2})$

Comment: Thanks -- new to multivariable calc.

Comment: @FouadSaffar You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ gives $\frac{3x^2y}{x^4-2x^2y+5y^2}=\frac{3t^4}{t^4-2t^4+5t^4}=\frac{3t^4}{4t^4}=\frac{3}{4}$ so the limit is $\frac{3}{4}$ along this path to the origin while $(x,y)=(t,t)$ gives $\frac{3x^2y}{x^4-2x^2y+5y^2}=\frac{3t^3}{4t^4}=\frac{3t^3}{t^4-2t^3+5t^2}=\frac{3t}{t^2-2t+5}$ so the limit is $0$ along this other path to the origin.